# using multiprocessing to compress large number of files

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to compress around 95 files each of size 7 gigs using python multiprocessing module:

```
import os;
from shutil import copyfileobj;
import bz2;
import multiprocessing as mp
import pprint
from numpy.core.test_rational import numerator

''' Input / Output Path '''

ipath = 'E:/AutoConfirm/'
opath = 'E:/compressed-autoconfirm/'

''' Number of Processes '''
num_of_proc = 6

def compressFile(fileName,chunkSize=100000000):
    global ipath
    print 'Started Compressing %s to %s'%(fileName,opath)
    inp = open(ipath+fileName,'rb')
    output = bz2.BZ2File(opath+fileName.split('/')[-1].strip('.csv')+'.bz2','wb',compresslevel=9)
    copyfileobj(inp,output,chunkSize)
    print 'Finished Compressing %s to %s'%(fileName,opath)

def process_worker(fileList):
    for x in fileList:
        compressFile(x)

def split_list(tempList):
    a , reList = 0, []
    global num_of_proc
    for x in range(num_of_proc+1):
        reList.append([tempList[a:a+len(tempList)/num_of_proc]])
        a = a + len(tempList)/num_of_proc
    return reList

pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_of_proc)
''' Prepare a list of all the file names '''
tempList = [x for x in os.listdir(ipath)]

''' Split the list into sub-lists 
    For example : if I have 90 files and I am using 6 processes 
                  each of the process will work on 15 files each '''

iterList = split_list(tempList)

''' print iterList >> [ [filename1, filename2] , [filename3,filename4], ... ] '''    


''' Pass the list consisting of sub-lists to pool '''
pool.map(process_worker,iterList)
```

The above code ends up creating 90 processes instead of 6. Can anyone help me identify the defect in the code.

Comment: You shouldn't do the splitting up of files by hand: just feed the complete list of (90) files to multiprocess, and let it handle it by itself. If correct, it will limit itself automatically to 6 processes at a time.

Comment: I tried that, but it kept creating new processes and my system exploded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiprocessing will re-import the module, so as everything is top level it does it all again, and again, and again.

You need to put the code in a function and call it.

```
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```